# Show table contents for each id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am kinda new at PHP.
I am making a webpage in which the user can register "cases" and for each case there will be multiple payments for multiple types of payments. There are three types of payments (let's name them LK, TK, and PP) and I am trying to make a modal in which the user can add new payments and underneath the "adding payment" section, in an HTML table there will be all the payments that have been made for that type of payment for that case. The cases and payments are 2 different SQL tables. When the table row of the first case gets clicked, a modal will show up in which are the above details. What I need to do is that when I click the first row, payments of the first case will show on the table, and the same when I click the second row (second case).

I am trying with this:

```
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * 
                    FROM tbl_payments 
                    INNER JOIN tbl_cases ON tbl_payments.db_id=tbl_cases.cs_id")
```

but it shows the payments for all cases.

In other words what I am trying to do is: show certain SQL records for certain SQL record of another table.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

The table cell that I click to show the modal:

```
<td data-title="LK" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#debt_modal"><?php echo $row['prod_db']; ?></td>
```

The modal table:

```
                <thead>
                <?php
                  $pmres = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tbl_payments INNER JOIN tbl_PO WHERE tbl_payments.db_pono=tbl_PO.po_no") or die(mysql_error());
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Test1</th>
                        <th>Test2</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($pmres,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){if($row['pm_db_am'] != "0") {?>
                      <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['pm_db_am']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['pm_date']; ?></td>
                        </td> 
                      </tr>
                  <?php }}; ?>
                </tbody>
```

Both tables have ids in their structure.

Comment: Dont you just need a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried with WHERE as well, it shows all payments

Comment: **Ajax** is the solution. At click, send variables to PHP to make the WHERE clause, then, at **Ajax** success you can add the rows given by PHP. Or for more help, show us all the code html/js/php

Comment: So show us your query with the where clause.

Comment: @Roy I added some parts of my code. Basically if I put manually the db_pono value (db_pono = 1;) it will show me the payments with that id, but then the same happens with every row (every row shows the same payment). What I need is to just separate rows so it shows correct payment for each row

Comment: @Roy also if I would have to do that it would mean sending data back and forth, is that possible without refreshing?

Comment: @xPersonx Yes, with Ajax. read: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

As Roy said in the comments, using ajax fixed my problem. I used jQuery and data attributes to make them differ and then used jQuery $.post to send the ID in another file in which I added the SQL table and matched the IDS using "WHERE". Also I made it so when I click Cancel in the modal the table gets removed.

Thanks